# Can I use "hasPart" to link WPHeader and WPFooter to WebPage?

Tags: schema.org, headers, footer

According to the Schema.org description, the property `hasPart` is defined for `CreativeWork`, i.e. `Article`. So, we can link different pages of `Article` for example.

But can we link `WPHeader` and `WPFooter` to `WebPage` with this property? Logically they are both parts of `WebPage` (but not `CreativeWork` type).

Or maybe internal folded HTML tags define it properly?

Comment: In your recent questions about Schema.org you always added the tag [tag:microformats] (and I always removed it). Please don’t use this tag unless you have a question about Microformats. (Microformats have nothing to do with Schema.org.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WPHeader`](http://schema.org/WPHeader) and [`WPFooter`](http://schema.org/WPFooter) *are* some kind of `CreativeWork`.

You can see this in their type hierarchies (displayed at the top of every Schema.org type’s page):

> `Thing` > `CreativeWork` > `WebPageElement` > `WPHeader`

> `Thing` > `CreativeWork` > `WebPageElement` > `WPFooter`

So having `WPHeader`/`WPFooter` as value for the [`hasPart` property](http://schema.org/hasPart) is perfectly fine ("expected"), and using `hasPart` to denote that the `WPHeader`/`WPFooter` is part of a `WebPage` seems to be appropriate, too (header/footer are "in some sense" part of a web page).

---

That said, in my opinion there is no point to use the `WPHeader`/`WPFooter` types on normal web pages (details: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867175/1591669), [2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218014/34147), [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/118903/16414)).

Comment: As far as  understand (i saw links 1,2,3)- If i don't have content (schema.org-type) in WPHeader and WPFooter - i don't need these entities. These elements of my page will be recognized via '<header>' and '<footer>' tags of HTML markup. Right? And what about WPSidebar inside '<aside>' tag? I have SiteNavigationElement inside it. Can i omit it?

Comment: @Evgeny: A parser looking only for Microdata/RDFa/JSON-LD will not recognize HTML5’s `header`/`footer` elements. The question is, why should these parsers be interested in your header/footer (or sidebar, or navigation, etc.)? Exceptions aside (e.g., you want to license your `WPHeader` under some different license than your other content on that page), I think these are not really interesting, because they (typically) don’t contain any interesting/relevant content. Consumers that *are* interested in your page structure (~ header, footer, sidebar) should look into in your HTML. My opinion.